# How To Delete Ubuntu and Change to Windows Permanently?

Tags: windows

I have something i want to download that is not available on Ubuntu and can't be open with Wine. I want to delete and switch to Windows. Can anyone give me step by step how to change to Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, rethink this. Make sure you backup the files you want. If you are sure about the decision follow the steps:

1- Buy a Windows 10 License

2- Download Windows 10 ISO file from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

3- Burn the ISO file into a flash drive (there are several tools for that. Look it up)

4- Put the flash drive

5- Restart the device

6- Go to the BIOS (See your device's catalog or google it to find the key combination that opens BIOS).

7- From the BIOS Make the flash drive the Boot device (There is usually a list of boot devices. You'll find your computer's HDD and the flash drive. Make the flash drive the first on the list).

8- Restart

9- Now The Windows 10 installation screen should appear. Follow the steps. They include putting your license number. Also you need to perform a clean install to delete everything. This video and several others could help : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzr16pxybnI

10- Wait until it finishes installing.

11- Congrats !!